# Remove word from one column base on another column then create and put it in new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-2.7

So, for example, I have this Dataframe:

```
branch_name        | address
Mcdonald's - BGC   | 2nd str. BGC
Jollibee - Taguig  | BGC, Taguig
...
```

How will I be able to remove words from `branch_name` base on the words that is in the `address` like the data below then create a new column to store the output per row.

```
branch_name        | address       | store_name
Mcdonald's - BGC   | 2nd str. BGC  | Mcdonald's
Jollibee - Taguig  | BGC, Taguig   | Jollibee
...
```

For expected output, the special characters has also been remove except apostrophe.

Comment: You have python 2.7 tagged what version of pandas is this? Currently available features differ greatly from earlier versions.

Comment: pandas==0.24.2 @HenryEcker

Answer (score -1):

You can use `df.str.extract` using regex:

```
df['store_name'] = df.branch_name.str.extract('(\S+)')
```

Comment: It only get the first word of the store. For example: "Ichi Station - Porta Vittoria", it only get "Ichi".